# Equivalence between Diffie Hellman and Discrete Log

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-complexity, computer-science, computational-number-theory, cryptography

For which non-trivial groups, do we know that the Diffie Hellman problem and the Discrete Log are equivalent?

Is there any group for which we suspect them to be different?

Could there be a finite list of groups where if Diffie Hellman problem and the Discrete Log are equivalent then Diffie Hellman problem and the Discrete Log are equivalent over any group they can be defined?

Answer (score 2):

If the Discrete Log is easy, so is computationally DH.

According to:

[Diﬁie-Hellman is as Strong as Discrete Log for Certain Primes](http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/2670/2670A.pdf)

> they [DH] conjectured that breaking their scheme would be as hard as taking discrete logarithms. This problem has remained open for the multiplicative group modulo a prime $P$ that they originally proposed. Here it is proven that both problems are (probabilisticly) polynomial—time equivalent if the totient of $P-1$ has only small prime factors with respect to $2 \log{P}$

Comment: Beware of asymptotic equivalences! For groups of realistic size, say $|G| \approx 2^{256}$, standard conjectures on the difficulty of the computational Diffie-Hellman problem assume $2^{128}$ difficulty, same as discrete log. Applying the reduction above requires $2^16$ calls to the DH oracle. As a result we only get out that DH is as hard as $2^102$, which is weaker than the commonly used conjecture, and a substantial gap from our best algorithms. So while the above paper suggests an asymptotic equivalence, the constant factors make it hard to apply in practice.

Comment: @WatsonLadd believe I cited correctly.

Comment: You did, but the results are considerably weaker than what is commonly assumed true. So when someone gives an explicit reduction to CDH, the protocol won't be as secure if they were to use the above paper instead of the standard conjecture, and the difference is significant.

Comment: Note that joro's reference is about [CDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_Diffie–Hellman_assumption), rather than [DDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decisional_Diffie–Hellman_assumption). $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Indeed, but I thought the OP asked about CDH, not DDH (DDH in some pairing based crypto is easy, while DL is considered hard).

Comment: Note that they are not known to be equivalent if the factors of phi(p) are not known... Perhaps they are equivalent but no one has proved it yet